# Recovering the matrix when the Schur decomposition of its blocks are known

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, matrix-analysis, eigenvector

Let E be a real symmetric matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $ n=2m$ and

$$E=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
G & X \\
X^t & H
\end{array}\right)$$
where $G,H,X$ are $m\times m$ matrices.

Suppose that $E^2=I$ and  the Schur decompositions of the blocks $G,H,X$ are given as follow

$$G=\Lambda^t_1 D_1 \Lambda_1$$
$$H=\Lambda^t_2 D_2 \Lambda_2$$
$$X=\Gamma^{-1} D_3 \Gamma$$
($D_j$s are diagonal matrices and $\Lambda^t_j=\Lambda^{-1}_j$  )

Can we extract any basis consisting eigenvectors of $E$ based on the assumptions?

Comment: Shouldn't $\Gamma$ be orthogonal, too, and $D_3$ in general triangular, if that is supposed to be a Schur decomposition?

Comment: Anyhow I'd be very surprised if there were something better than recomputing the decomposition from scratch.

Comment: The question is concerned with  a basis consisting of  eigenvectors of $E$.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify whether you want a Schur decomposition or a basis of eigenvectors. The two are not the same thing.